# Django rest framework get user profile data for logged in user

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have created Models UserProfile, serilzers and ModelViewSet like below. From below models I want to fetch loged in User profile details like state, city and adress etc

```
 class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='userprofile');
    state= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    add1= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    add2= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    postalcode= models.IntegerField()
    country= models.CharField(max_length=200)


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('state','city','country')



class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class=UserProfileSerializer
    def get(self, request):
        userProfileObj = queryset.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(userProfileObj)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

But for some reason, I am getting all user profile data instead of logged in user data, please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by overriding the `get_queryset()` method, as below

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return self.queryset
```

Here the `'list'` refferes the api type, which is `list api`. That means, it will return logged-in user's profile while you accessing the **list api**

Comment: But I am getting this error Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'state'.

Answer (score 1):

`ModelViewSet` implements the methods `list`/`retrieve` not `get`.

Just overwrite `get_queryset` instead. No need for creating serializer yourself. (There's no need to set `queryset` attribute as well.)